# post function in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, post

I try to create a query getting from a formular through post function. The post function must pass a text and an int variable to create the query sent to database.

When I start execute my php script, it says: undefined index, for the int variable.

I dont understand why the int variable isn't recognized. here is my code:

formulaire04.php

```
<form action="selection_jeux.php" method="post">
    <p>
    Nom
    <input type="text" name="possesseur"/>
        Prix maximum
    <input type="int" name="prixmax"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
    </p>
</form>

selection_jeux.php

<?php
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test' , 'root', '');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT nomselec, prix FROM jeux_video WHERE possesseur = :possesseur AND prix <= :prixmax');
    $req->execute(array('possesseur'=> $_POST['possesseur'], 'prixmax'=> $_POST['prixmax']));

    echo '<ul>';

    while($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
        echo '<li>'  . $donnees['nom'] . ' (' . $donnees['prix'] . ' EUR)</li>'; 
    }
    echo '<li>';

    $req->closeCursor();
?>
```

Comment: `int` isn't a valid value for the `type` attribute of an HTML `<input>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue is in the SQL Statement not the HTML markup**

**On your prepare statement you have SELECT nomselec,prix
but on your while statement you have $donnees['nom'] not nomselec**

Could that be the issue?

To all the people saying int isn't a valid type, this does not matter it still gets posted as normal;

Example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<p>
Nom
<input type="text" name="possesseur"/>
Prix maximum
<input type="int" name="prixmax"/>
<input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [possesseur] => test [prixmax] => 123 )
```

Comment: The int was not the main problem you were right. but even with the new code, the screen displays nothing (no error message hopefully)

Answer (score 2):

Oh,

well, it's just basic HTML

```
<input type="text">
```

doesn't mean that content will be a string, it's just a kind of input.

`<input type="int">` just doesn't exist...

Accepted types for input (HTML4)

- button
- checkbox
- file
- hidden
- image
- password
- radio
- reset
- submit
- text

Accepted types for input (HTML5)

- button
- checkbox
- color
- date
- datetime
- datetime-local
- email
- file
- hidden
- image
- month
- number
- password
- radio
- range
- reset
- search
- submit
- tel
- text
- time
- url
- week

Comment: The closest to `int` is `type=number` which although supported by a few browsers, isn't supoorted by all properly: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html#t04

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no input type called int.

http://de.selfhtml.org/html/referenz/attribute.htm#input

Answer (score 0):

use <`input type="number">`
 HTML5 input types are

```
color
date
datetime
datetime-local
email
month
number
range
search
tel
time
url
week
```